# What are soft classes?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, tensorflow

When reading the help page of [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits), I came across the term soft classes. I read that soft classes have ground truth labels which are a probability distribution on their one hot encodings. How do you intuitively interpret the information a soft class label provides (the probability distribution)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hard classes** mean one-hot encoded distributions like:

```
y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Having labels like that means that any output distribution will be penalized to force the network output the class `2` (zero-indexed).

In some cases, it's ok for the network to output any of two or more classes, e.g., class `0` or class `2`. A particular example is a [SkipGram model](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/) for word embeddings (if we ignore the issues of a large vocabulary). You can't do that with hard classes, other than create two training instances with two different labels:

```
x -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
x -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

As a result, the weights will probably bounce back and forth, because the two examples push them in different directions. That's when **soft classes** can be helpful. They allow you to train the network with the label like:

```
x -> [0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0]
```

Note that this is a valid probability distribution and it matches the cross-entropy loss. But it's more explicit for the network: classes `0` and `2` are both correct, so the network should boost both. It will learn to match `[0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0]` distribution directly as opposed to alternating `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.

By the way, if you're interested in more subtleties of cross-entropy losses in tensorflow, read also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995) on SO.

Comment: The possible use of soft classes in the skip gram model was a nice example. Obtained a good insight into the practical use cases of soft classes from your answer. Thanks.